# Is there a Windows equivalent of the HAProxy for virtual load balancing?

Tags: windows-server-2008, load-balancing, haproxy

I want to load balance a bunch of VMs, but don't have any Linux boxes available.  Typically, afaik, it's done with HAProxy on Linux.

Is there an HAProxy equivalent on Windows? (free, open-source if possible).

Comment: Product recon is against the FAQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Microsoft Network Load Balancing. It works well (we've used it for a few years), however its Layer 3/4 AFAIK - ie it won't detect if your IIS is down.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use ISA server infront of it but that comes with another set of issues i.e. it becomes a SPOF

A linux VM running something like HAProxy, Pound, Varnish etc. might fit your needs.